# SQL Inner Join wont join

Tags: sql, join

I've got the following table structure but when I try the below select statement I get back an empty result with no data.  I'm trying to get the data from table A where it links up with table B and the section is new.  So in this example I should get rows; two and three.

What am I doing wrong ?  :s

Thanks in advance

```
table A
id name primarygroup
1  one        1
2  two        2
3  three      2

table B
id    section
1     old
2     new
3     young

SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.primarygroup = B.id
WHERE B.section = "new"
```

Comment: Well, probably stupid, but did you try `'new'` instead of `"new"`, or are you sure there's no space in your data ?

Comment: Are you actually using double quotes (`"`)?. You need to use single quotes `WHERE B.section = 'new'`

Comment: Ah thanks guys!  That was driving me crazy

Comment: @HeavyHead, what was the difference between the answers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [this SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4358b/2). Your query is correct, just need to change the double quotes by single quotes. So instead of "new" try 'new'

And by the way, edit your tags and add wich RDBMS are you using. My sample code is for SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

try `single quotes` **"** -> **'**

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.primarygroup = B.id
WHERE B.section = 'new'
```

Also, Edit your query to select the fields you want, or you are getting `id` twice there.